# What are the differences between Libav intern encoder and libvo-aacenc?

Tags: constants, aac, encoder, libav

Is libvo-aacenc in Libav Library a different encoder as the intern aac encoder (listed under encoders after configuring the makefile). If yes what could be the possible resons when running ./configure --enable-libvo-aacenc I receive the message:

```
libvo_aacenc is version3 and --enable-version3 is not specified.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
libav-tools@libav.org mailing list or IRC #libav on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
```

Which files should be generated by activating the libvo-aacenc? Which constants are contained by it?

Answer (score 0):

`libvo-aacenc` is licensed un GPL3 and `ffmpeg` is licensed under GLP2. Including `libvo-aacenc`in the binary changes the license of your ffmpeg build to GPL3 (because GPL3 overrides GPL2 in this case). So you must set that flag to acknowledge you understand that your binary has additional legal restrictions.

No files are generated, not constants are contained.

Comment: I set the flag: "./configure --enable-static --enble-version3 --enable-libvo-aacenc". I receive the error "ERROR libvo_aacenc not found".

Comment: do you have libvo-aacenc dev libraries installed?

Comment: I use this library: https://libav.org/releases/libav-12.3.tar.gz. Installed locally in the folder.

Comment: Ok, this conversation is no longer related to the original question. If you have a new question, please make a new post.